# In PERL how to pull records into array

Tags: perl, perl-data-structures

in perl ,

I have table, i have fields like RANGE1, RANGE2, AND RECORDS around 6,

i want to bring these 6 records into array, somthing like

```
@arr = (range1_record_1, range2_record_1, 
        range1_record_2, range2_record_2, 
        range1_record_3, range2_record_3, 
        range1_record_4, range2_record_4, 
        range1_record_5, range2_record_5);
```

How to pull records into array,

Comment: How is your table represented?

Comment: I think you'd better show what you are doing now so people have some clue where to start answering you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using DBI, try [fetchall_arrayref](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?DBI#fetchall_arrayref).

Comment: And nobody knows what you are fetching them from or how.